# How to get user info with Google Fit integration in Android

Tags: android, google-fit

I am integrating Google Fit app into Android app to tracking Fitness data (get steps count) by using SENSORS_API and HISTORY_API
How can I get user infor (email or user id) with that API

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Perfect example for you, this may help you

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/google-fit-for-android-history-api--cms-25856

Comment: I am also unable to get the "Email". Anybody found any solution?

Comment: I answered it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57271875/get-current-logged-in-user-info-email-or-userid-from-google-fit-api/60136324#60136324

Comment: This example is deprecated by now.