# Get current logged in user info (email or userid) from google fit API

Tags: ionic4, google-fit

I am integrating google fit APIs for tracking fitness activities and I need to display logged in user email, but I am not able to fetch user info like email or userid from google fit.

I have found https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataSources/get but I need to add userId and dataSourceId in request parameters which I am unable to find.

Comment: Similar here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40779598/how-to-get-user-info-with-google-fit-integration-in-android

Comment: Not a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the wrong place.

The data you are looking for is under: **People API v1**.

Use the following scopes for oAuth:

*https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email*

Following url to fetch data:
*https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me*

A get call with **access_token** should be good for you. Enjoy :)